# Printing arrays from pointers, only the first element prints

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I am trying to print an array of structures using the returned pointer to the first element then using pointer arithmetic to print out the array.

The way i am doing it works for the ships array, but when i try to print the assets array only the first element prints, all though i am using exactly the same technique! does anybody have any idea why this is the case?

an FYI: the assets array is correctly filled, if i print out in the function where i fill the array all the values are correct.

attempting to print the array:

```
    size_t ship_size;
    size_t asset_size;

    ship* ship_ptr;
    rescue_asset* assets_ptr;

    ship_ptr = read_ship_locations(&ship_size);
    assets_ptr = read_rescue_assets(&asset_size);

    int z;

    for (z = 0; z < asset_size; z++) 
    {
      printf("asset %d \t callsign: %s \n", z, (assets_ptr + z)->callsign);
    }
```

returning the assets array:

```
rescue_asset* read_rescue_assets(size_t* size)
{
  no_of_lines = count_lines(locof);

  assets = calloc(no_of_lines, sizeof(rescue_asset));

  *size = (size_t) no_of_lines;

  //fill array

  return assets;
}
```

result of the printing:

```
asset 0      callsign: Rescue_169 
asset 1      callsign:  
[and so on ...]
asset 36     callsign:
```

I think this is the problem, it seems to only save to the first element in the array:

This is my fill array function:

```
for (i = 0; i < no_of_lines; i++) {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s %c %s %lf %lf %f %u %u", assets[i].callsign,
                &assets[i].type, assets[i].base, &assets[i].loc.lat,
                &assets[i].loc.lng, &assets[i].speed, &assets[i].max_deploy_time,
                &assets[i].service_time) != EOF) {
            printf("asset: %d \t callsign: %s \n", i, assets[i].callsign);

         }
  }
```

This is the result of this method:

```
asset: 0     callsign: Angle_Lifeboat 
asset: 0     callsign: Angle_ILB 
asset: 0     callsign: Broad_Haven_ILB 
[and so on ...]
asset: 0     callsign: Rescue_116 
asset: 0     callsign: Rescue_122 
asset: 0     callsign: Rescue_169
```

Comment: It looks as if this line `//fill array` fails.

Comment: but  inside that //fill array segment of code, if i loop through the array and print each element it all displays fine.

Comment: You probably print some intermediate variable's value ... - dare it and show the code doing it.

Comment: Not absolutely sure, but I think @alk is subtly suggesting       [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: **Post the code for the inconveniently-omitted `//fill array`** (and probably `count_lines(locof)` as well, since there is the definite possibility you're not properly rewinding your input file).

Comment: Hu... @WhozCraig ok, now we know you're here tonight ... ;-)

Comment: Guys i have found the problem but im not sure why its doing it, the fill array code over writes the first element each time but im not sure whats going on. code being add now.

Comment: @alk fully-caffeinated and ready to go =P

Comment: Why the while-loop in the for-loop?

Comment: @alk post that as an answer and I'll *happily* up vote it.

Comment: @alk No, the while loop that consumes the entire file and before `i` is ever incremented to `1` =P (and 'm not all that fond of `scanf()` myself). It would have helped tremendously had the OP been accurate in the description: "only the first element is set" to include the detail: "with the last value".

Comment: @WhozCraig ye sorry about that, im dyslexic so i have difficulty explaining things :/ thanks everyone though! i was just being an idiot

Comment: @chrisedwards no worries. glad your problem was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index to `assets` is incremented in the outer `for`-loop.

The reading fully happens in the inner `while`-loop with `i` staying constant.

Get rid of the `for`-loop and increment `i` after every successful call to `fscanf()`.

Comment: +1 Or make the `while` an `if` with a `break` as an `else` consequence. . either works, but doing as I described eliminates the risk of overrunning the array.

Comment: Yup got it, cheers. in fact i removed the while and replaced it with an if :) i was just being stupid cheers alk.

Comment: LOL. You don't like much do you =P

Comment: "*doowy, doowy...doo - wydoowydoo*" and "*reedreedreedreed*" simply sounds better then "*fonexfonex*" or "*skänphskänphskänph*" %->